# jquery copy element on blur event for dynamic id

Tags: jquery

I need to copy the text from id=a-0 in id=b-0 when the event blur() occur and the same if they enter something in a-1 then it should copy the text to c-1. But since I have many rows (a-x) I can't use the id as the trigger.

So on blur of an a-# input, each b-# and c-# input gets the same value of the corresponding a-# input

Each TR tag represent a row.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input class="abc" id="a-0" value="test"></td>
<td><input class="abc" id="b-0"></td>
<td><input class="abc" id="c-0"></td>
</tr>
<tr>  
    <td><input class="abc" id="a-1"></td>
    <td><input class="abc" id="b-1"></td>
    <td><input class="abc" id="c-1"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have the following code so I have the value from the id but how can I copy it to id=b-x

```
 $('.abc').blur(function(){

        $('#' + this.id).val()

    })
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what your want to copy, and to where you want to copy... Could you try to clarify?

Comment: I don't follow the logic here. Why does the first group from a-0 to b-0, but the second group from a-1 to c-1?

Comment: @j08691 I think the logic of a-x and b-x copy to c-x applies to all of them but OP did not explain too well

Comment: sorry not to good in english...it is a table with x representing the row

Comment: So on blur of an `a-#` input, each `b-#` and `c-#` input gets the same value of the corresponding `a-#` input?

Comment: Yes @PatrickQ each b-#

Comment: Only `b-#`? Or both `b-#` _and_ `c-#`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.abc').blur(function () {
    $(this).parent().nextAll().find('input').val($(this).val())
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/94jAZ/)**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to analyze the `id`.

This is a working example:

```
$('.abc').blur(function(event){

    var sourceId = this.id;

    var index = sourceId.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    var targetId = 'b-' + index;

    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#' + targetId).val(value);

});
```

Such a proper formed id, you can also split and analyze the index number as well as the letter.

You could also consider using free attributes like `<input data-index="1" id="something" ...>`. Then, in the callback, get the data-index directly as number by `$(this).prop('data-index')`. The `data-index` doesn't have to be unique, this is your advantage.